# How can I update Twig in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, twig

I am trying to update Twig in Symfony 4 like this:

```
composer require twig/twig
```

The error message is:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - twig/extensions is locked to version v1.5.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - twig/extensions v1.5.4 requires twig/twig ^1.27|^2.0 -> found twig/twig[v1.27.0, ..., v1.44.2, v2.0.0, ..., v2.14.4] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.3).
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of `composer.json` and your attempts to resolve the problem. For example, which parts of that message are unclear to you?

Comment: If you want to update your dependencies, run `composer update`.

Comment: `composer require` is for installing, not updating. For update, it's `composer update <package>`. You should display your composer.json. Is it only this packages you wan to update ?

Comment: If you are are still having trouble then create a fresh 4.4 project and add your additional third party stuff.  It's possible that a third party package is causing the issue.  At that point you will hopefully have a working reference composer.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often easiest to first remove the package that's blocking the update and then install it again after the update. First do:

```
composer remove twig/extensions
```

and then

```
composer require twig/twig
composer require twig/extensions
```

This should first remove the extensions, update twig and then install the extensions again.

Comment: I tried it, removing twig worked, but reinstall did not work anymore. Now I do not have twig anymore :(

Comment: Did you remove twig/extensions? What error are you getting now?

Comment: I removed my commit to an old version and made composer install again. Now I do not try to remove twig again, because the reinstall does not work

Comment: You don't need to remove twig, just remove the twig extensions.

Answer (score -1):

please try this:

```
composer update twig/twig
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase: This is different than the previous answer.

Comment: How is this different?  If `twig/twig` was already installed (according to the error from the initial post), how could updating it resolve the problem?